# Git-svn get all revision history

Tags: git, git-svn

When I first started my project, I did a `git svn clone -rN` of the latest revision in my repo. However, I would like see all the code's history via `git blame`/`annotate`.

How do I check out all the revisions that I've missed from the repo? I am fully aware that I can just make another dir and clone again but I want to know if there is any other options.

Comment: Doesn't `git svn clone` grab all the revisions from Subversion by default? Did you do anything special not to get all of them?

Comment: @Chris, forgot to insert -rN option in my post where N is the latest revision.